# Test multiple Assemblies with NUnit3

Tags: powershell, nunit

I want to test more than one Assemblypath with nunit3. This was in nunit 2.x easy but since i have nunit 3.2 it doesn't work.

My code looks so:

```
[string]$path= "C:\CMI\Entwicklung\MetaTool\.build\temp\_PublishedNUnitTests\CMI.Server.DirectImport.Tests\CMI.Server.DirectImport.Tests.dll, C:\CMI\Entwicklung\MetaTool\.build\temp\_PublishedNUnitTests\CMI.Server.DirectImport.Tests\CMI.Server.DirectImport.Tests.dll"

& $nunitExe $path -work "$NUnitTestResultsDirectory\NUnit.xml" -noheader
```

When i run this script an error appears which tells me, that the path is not a valid path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Project file would work, but isn't necessary. You just need to pass the paths with spaces separating them, rather than commas.

```
[string]$path1="C:\CMI\Entwicklung\MetaTool\.build\temp\_PublishedNUnitTests\CMI.Server.DirectImport.Tests\CMI.Server.DirectImport.Tests.dll"

[string]$path2="C:\CMI\Entwicklung\MetaTool\.build\temp\_PublishedNUnitTests\CMI.Server.DirectImport.Tests\CMI.Server.DirectImport.Tests.dll"

& $nunitExe $path1 $path2 -work "$NUnitTestResultsDirectory\NUnit.xml" -noheader
```

Comment: And if i don't know how many path i will have, how can i solve this?

Comment: You can specify as many paths as you need to on the command line, they just all need to be space separated, rather that comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an NUnit project file (.nunit). You can list multiple dlls there and some other settings. See here how to do it: http://nunit.org/index.php?p=projectEditor&r=2.6.4 There's no documentation for NUnit 3 yet.